# How can I draw a bar graph from three different data frames using matplotlib?

Tags: python, visualization, matplotlib

I want to draw a triple bar graph with three different dataframes using matplotLib

#### DF1

```
index | Number    
A     | 110    
B     | 22    
D     | 52
```

#### DF2

```
index | Number
A     | 100
B     | 22
C     | 52
```

#### DF3

```
index | Number    
A     | 90    
B     | 12    
C     | 10
```

I am trying to use this piece of code but this is giving error as for this data needs to be from same dataframe

```
ax=DF1[["Number"]].DF2[["Number"]].DF3[["Number"]].plot(kind ='bar',log=True,title = "BarGraph",figsize=(15,10),legend=True,fontsize=10)
ax.set_xlabel("Index",fontsize=12)
ax.set_ylabel("Number",fontsize=12)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Why don’t you use Seaborn instead?

Comment: Ok can you just guide me regarding how this thing can be done using seaborn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are willing to use seaborn, this code chunk works for you:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

DF1 = pd.DataFrame({'index': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'Number': [110, 22, 52]})
DF2 = pd.DataFrame({'index': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'Number': [100, 22, 52]})
DF3 = pd.DataFrame({'index': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'Number': [90, 12, 10]})

DF = pd.concat([DF1, DF2, DF3])
DF['df_num'] = ['1','1','1','2','2','2','3','3','3']

sns.barplot(data = DF, x='index', y='Number', hue='df_num')
```

It should produce this plot:

[image: seaborn plot]